# Попытка доступа к `richTextBox2`не из того потока - как это исправить?

Tags: c#, listview

Программа: обрабатывает текст (считает слова, и т.д.).

В программе: есть метод, в котором собирается строка:

```
private void PrintResume()
{
    strText.Append("Первая строка: " + int1 + Environment.NewLine);
    strText.Append("Вторая строка: " + int2 + Environment.NewLine);

    richTextBox2.Text += strText.ToString();
}
```

И соответственно, `richTextBox2`, который находится внутри `tabPage6`.

Работает нормально, за исключением случая, если переключить таб (их несколько, с richTextBox'ами и listview'и). В этом случае программа начинает ругаться, что "`попытка доступа к richTextBox2 не из того потока, в котором он был создан`". Причем, если переключать на табы с listview, этого не происходит.

В чем тут проблема может быть?

Comment: Тут что-то другое, по крайней мере в этой формулировке. С чего бы ошибке с потоками проявляться только при переключении вкладок?

Answer (score 3):

Истинную причину проблемы, исключая изложенную в тексте `Exception`'а, мне назвать сложно.
Я советую попробовать обойти ее, используя следующий код:

```
if (richTextBox2.InvokeRequired)
    richTextBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { richTextBox2.Text += strText.ToString(); }));
else
    richTextBox2.Text += strText.ToString();
```

Вместо

```
richTextBox2.Text += strText.ToString();
```

Comment: `new MethodInvoker` имеет смысл убрать.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня без него не компилируется. Неужели у Вас компилируется?

Comment: Аргументы в лямбду добавь. `(s, e) => `

Comment: @Qwertiy это не помогает, разумеется. Пожалуйста, вооружитесь компилятором и попробуйте сами.

Comment: Сорри, (s, e) - это я с событиями перепутал. Но лямбда как-то точно должна передаваться без оборачивания. Попозже проверю.